# What can be grabbed with the Advanced Grabbing Unit?

Tags: kerbal-space-program

I'm curious as to what can be grabbed with the Advanced Grabbing Unit from the Asteroid Redirect Mission update. The [wiki](http://wiki.kerbalspaceprogram.com/wiki/Advanced_Grabbing_Unit) says that it can "pick up just about anything," but that's just not reassuring enough. Can it grab space debris from orbit? How large does the object have to be in order to be grabbed? Any videos of it?

Comment: asteroids and debris at least. atm, i cannot think of anything else that would make sense..

Comment: It can also grab Kerbals.

Comment: Well yeah, I know that it can grab kerbals. But besides kerbals and asteroids...

Comment: I recently decided to clean up the debris on my sandbox world. This involved a [mission to the Mun to retrieve a single decoupler](http://i.imgur.com/GMLY0uI.jpg).

Comment: There is a legend that's usually whispered around campfires, that says to never, never grab a Kerbal with two Advanced Grabbing Units, because it will destroy the world. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kTg3vB8x3TY

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The short answer is:

"Anything that does not have a [Sphere of Influence](http://wiki.kerbalspaceprogram.com/wiki/Sphere_of_influence)"

Anything you have built and have launched or is sitting on the launchpad, asteroids, kerbals. You can use the claw to attach to these

You can't use the claw to attach to Duna or Mun or anything else like that

As per OP's request: [video footage of it being used on something other than an Asteroid](http://youtu.be/5jboapUKRwY?t=3m46s)

Comment: So why aren't there any videos of people grabbing things other than asteroids and kerbals? That's my other question.

Comment: Edited my answer to include a video of the claw being used outside of "Grabbing an Asteroid or a Kerbal". I suspect the reason you don't find many videos of this is because the only difference between this and docking, is the absence of a docking port on the target.

Comment: I can confirm that the Klaw can grab space debris like decoupled stages or entire ships. I haven't found anything that it can't grab other than what's listed in this answer.

Comment: So, aside from playing with asteroids, we now have a way to collect all the garbage we've been leaving in orbit up until this point? Sweet!

Comment: That we do that we do, fight that Kessler syndrome!

Comment: What about KSC buildings?

Comment: I've seen no indication that building or the wreckage of them can be effected by the claw. In 24 they were just terrain features, now they're terrain features with destruction animations

Comment: A few mentions of collecting garbage ... Is just "cancelling" debris from the tracking station considered a form of cheating..?

Comment: It's your game @GrimmTheOpiner if avoiding debris isn't something you find enjoyable then feel free to cancel it. There used to be a setting that controlled how many debris could exist before the game would automatically start deleting them. Not sure if it's still there.

Answer (score 2):

They can grab onto other ships/stations/satellites as well. If you launched ships without docking ports that need rescuing/refueling, launch a refueling vessel with an Advanced Grabbing Unit, and it can latch onto the stranded ship and is then considered "docked" with the other ship, and can transfer fuel to it.

Comment: So, what's the downvote for? Something in my answer inaccurate?